# named system mutex not recognized

Tags: c#, .net, mutex

I am trying named system mutex approach to synchronize two processes-

1. a c# windows service
2. a desktop c# app

When the mutex is created, process that didn't create the mutex doesn't seem to detect the existing mutex. Below in more detail:

Windows service is responsible for creating the mutex(No prefixes-Global/Local etc. Just a normal named system mutex) as follows:

```
        Mutex myMutex= null;
        try
        {
            myMutex= Mutex.OpenExisting(myMutexName);

        }
        catch (WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException x)
        {
            //doesn't exist. 
            try
            {
                this.GetLogger().Info("Create Mutex");
                bool createdNew = false;
                new Mutex(false, myMutexName, out createdNew);
                if (!createdNew) throw new Exception("Unable to create Mutex");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Stop();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            this.Stop();
        }
        finally
        {

            if (myMutex!= null)
            {
                try
                {
                    myMutex.ReleaseMutex();
                }
                catch(Exception x)
                {
                    this.GetLogger().Warn("Unable to release mutex");
                }
            }
        }
```

I have this in onStart(). Also, elsewhere in the service I synchronize on this mutex.

Now, in the application I use it thus:

```
            Mutex myMutex= null;

        try
        {
            myMutex= Mutex.OpenExisting(this.myMutexName);
            myMutex.WaitOne();
//do required stuff


        }
        catch (WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException wcbox)
        {
            //doesn't exist yet. service not running??
            this.GetLogger().Error("Background Service is not Running");
            shutdownApp();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myMutex!= null)
            {
                try
                {
                    myMutex.ReleaseMutex();
                }
                catch (Exception x)
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

My issues:

1. With service is running, the app throws WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException which means it doesn't see the mutex which exists (I verified this using the tool "WinObj", mutex exists under "BaseNamedObjects" as type "Mutant"). Why? I run the service under same account as I am logged in. Even without, that shouldn't be the issue because named mutex is operating system wide object right?
2. I am not exactly clear on when the mutex will get destroyed. Currently, I see that the mutex gets created when I start the service and when I stop the service, I see the mutex no longer exists(WinObj). Does that mean mutex is garbage collected when there is no one waiting on it and when the creator process ends?
3. In general, what is the life cycle of a named system mutex. Specifically, when does it die?

Comment: Have you tried `Global\` prefix?

Comment: @AntonKovalenko - I do not want to try it because it relates to Terminal services etc. I want to stick to non prefixed names till someone tells what I am doing might not work. Handling terminal services user scenarios is not my requirement

Comment: The problem is, services (on modern windows) default to Global namespace, while apps in normal login sessions default to Local. Hence what you're doing might not work.

Comment: @Brian Namespaces aren't specific to terminal services. Your services and your applications run in different sessions. That's the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to share a mutex across sessions you must use either the `Global` namespace, or create your [own private namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684295.aspx).

As it stands, you are not specifying a namespace. And whilst the service defaults to use the global namespace, your interactive application will be using the local namespace.

Comment: For some more infor see [Mutext constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwe34f1k(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: i know it's an old thread (could i say pun intended) - is that true also of interactive services?  I had a look around MSDN which does indeed state what you said, but it didn't dive deeper to say if that applied also to interactive services.

Comment: @cineam there's no such thing as an interactive service

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i beg to differ. you might look at the interactive services detection [service].  that's the name microsoft gave it, so i will stick with it.

Comment: and for what it is worth, it does apply (my question above), i did my research yesterday. cheers

Comment: @cineam Interactive services existed in XP. They were removed in Vista.

Comment: they were disabled by default, not removed. it's just a registry bit flip to enable them and use them.

Comment: @cineammispelt I don't think so. Perhaps you can point me to this registry setting.

Answer (score -1):

@david i use a tool called google to easily find it, and we are running in production with interactive services detection enabled with an interactive service. interactive services detection cannot be started unless you switch that registry key.  i don't know what the debate is here: it's there, its documented, and google can easily point you to it.